# Facebook App Alerts: Permissions - read and write for apps without FB login

Tags: facebook

Facebook sent an `attention` alert about the permission the App is requesting:

```
Permissions

Your app asks for read and write permissions at the same time. You should only ask for write permissions when a user tries to share something to Facebook. Please update your app accordingly. Read our best practices for more details.
```

In fact during authentication App is requesting those permissions: 
`read_friendlists`, `publish_stream`, `offline_access`, `email`

But App is not using FB login so according to second point of this section "Publishing permissions", we can ask for both read and write permission:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#publishing

In this situation, can the Alert be ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "problem" with your request is the `read_friendlists` permission, the guidelines in case of non-facebook login says:

> In this case, make sure that the only read permissions you request are
>   public profile and friend list.

Also the `offline_access` han been deprecated and not useful anymore

So you should ask for `read_friendlists` in a separate request, the alert does not affect the functionality of the app but maybe it will affects other things like quota or apps store.

Hope this helps